# Generate Series from Rows in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, generate-series

I have a table of `reservations` which has two columns (`started_at`, and `ended_at`). I want to build a query that expands reservation rows into their individual days. So for instance if a reservation lasted 5 days I want 5 rows back for it. Something along the lines of:

### Current Output

```
id | started_at | ended_at
----------------------------
1  | 2016-01-01 | 2016-01-05
2  | 2016-01-06 | 2016-01-10
```

### Desired Output

```
id | date
---------------
1  | 2016-01-01
1  | 2016-01-02
1  | 2016-01-03
1  | 2016-01-04
1  | 2016-01-05
2  | 2016-01-06
2  | 2016-01-07
2  | 2016-01-08
2  | 2016-01-09
2  | 2016-01-10
```

I figured that `generate_series` might be of use here but I'm not certain of the syntax. Any help is greatly appreciated

### SQL Fiddle

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/f0135/1

Comment: Try `SELECT id, generate_series(started_at, ended_at, '1 day')
FROM reservations;`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This runs ok on your fiddle

```
SELECT id, to_char(generate_series(started_at, ended_at, '1 day'),'YYYY-MM-DD') as date
FROM reservations;
```

Comment: If looking to get `date` type for dates in the desired output, can use `generate_series(started_at, ended_at, '1 day')::date as date`. Conversion to string is not needed.